# Can not load "webpack", it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?

Tags: webpack, karma-webpack

ERROR [preprocess]: Can not load "webpack", it is not registered!
Perhaps you are missing some plugin?

Webpack version:
4.14.0

Webpack Karma version:
2.0.4

Karma version:
3.0.0

Linux

```
 module.exports = ( config ) => {
      config.set( {
        basePath: path.resolve( __dirname ),
        browsers: [ 'PhantomJS' ],
        files: [ {
          pattern: '../../../spec/**/*.spec.js',
          watch: true
        } ],
        preprocessors: {
          [ '../../../spec/**/*.spec.js' ]: [ 'webpack' ]
        },
        reporters: [ 'mocha' ],
        plugins: [
          'karma-webpack',
          'karma-mocha',
          'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
          'karma-mocha-reporter',
        ],
        webpack: {
          mode: 'development',
          target: 'web',
          module: {
            rules: [ {
              test: /\.js$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
              }
            } ]
          },
          resolve: {
            extensions: [ '.js', '.jsx ' ],
            modules: [ 'node_modules', 'src' ],
          }
        },
        webpackMiddleware: {
          noInfo: true,
          stats: {
            chunks: false
          }
        },
      } )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- phantomjs has been deprecated in favor of headless chrome.
- I use few different components over your sample above. jasmine over mocha, TypeScript over JavaScript.
- Also, if you you are using angular JS, it is important you load angular and angular-mocks part of files: []
- In my case for the preprocessor [webpack] to work, I had to add all four 'karma-jasmine', 'karma-chrome-launcher', 'karma-webpack', 'karma-typescript-preprocessor' in plugins: []
- Happy to post my webpack config as well, it is pretty standard. This error has nothing to do with webpack config, it is all in karma.conf.js.

Hope this helps!

This is my working karma.conf.js

```
'use strict';
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.test.js');//webpack config for test

process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();//Node library for headless Chrome, https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/

module.exports = (config) => {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        plugins: [
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-webpack',
            'karma-typescript-preprocessor'
        ],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['HeadlessChrome'],
        customLaunchers: {
            HeadlessChrome: {
                base: 'ChromeHeadless',
                flags: [
                    '--no-sandbox',
                    '--headless',
                    '--disable-gpu',
                    '--disable-translate',
                    '--disable-extensions'
                ]
            }
        },
        singleRun: process.argv.indexOf("--watch") === -1,
        autoWatchBatchDelay: 300,
        files: [
            './node_modules/angular/angular.js',
            './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            './src/test.ts'
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            './src/test.ts': ['webpack'],
        },
        client: {
            // This is important as there are a lot of tests that are reliant in the order that they were written.
            jasmine: {
                random: false
            }
        },
        webpack: webpackConfig,
        webpackMiddleware: {
            stats: {
                /* https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/commit/eb8bbf8e11779487d3af527f8b70644316075ee8
*/
                warningsFilter: /export .* was not found in/
            }
        }
    });
};
```